# Error while selecting location in Oracle EBS v12

Tags: oracle, forms, report, oracle-ebs

I am new to EBS. When I tried to select location under work structure I am getting the error. Snapshot is attached.

Anybody please help.[image]

Comment: Follow this [link](http://oracleappsguides.blogspot.com/2015/07/app-pay-06153system-error-procedure.html). The solution is provided with screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the System Administrator responsibility and use the System Profiles form to verify the following profile options are set properly for the responsibility that you are trying to use when you get the error:

- HR:Business Group
- HR:Security Profile

Set these correctly for the responsibility you are trying to use and the error should go away.